# How to change icon and the app name of the expo push notification?

Tags: react-native, expo

[Push Notification Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7X5t1.jpg)

I tried to change icon but could not but at least I need to change the app name there. If someone can help me with this issue. I really appreciate, thank you!

```
{"expo": {
"name": "App Name",
"notification": {
  "icon": "./assets/appGrey96.png",
  "color": "#3B3B3B",
  "iosDisplayInForeground": true
},
"description": "Demo",
"slug": "releasev2",
"version": "1.0.0",
"orientation": "portrait",
"icon": "./assets/appIcon.png",
"splash": {
  "image": "./assets/splash.png",
  "resizeMode": "contain",
  "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
},
"updates": {
  "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
},
"assetBundlePatterns": [
  "**/*"
],
"ios": {
  "supportsTablet": true,
  "bundleIdentifier": "IOS"
},
"android": {
  "adaptiveIcon": {
    "foregroundImage": "./assets/appIcon.png",
    "backgroundColor": "#50dbb6"
  },
  "package": "com.dummyRelease"
},
"web": {
  "favicon": "./assets/appIcon.png"
}
```

}
}

Answer (score 1):

Try in standalone build. It will be changed to the app's name and icon in standalone build.

If you are running your app in expo go then it will show expo go app's name and icon there. Will not do this in standalone build.

Comment: thank you for your answer. As you told it's correct I tried that by creating standalone app with FCM I'm able to receive the push notification with my app name and not expo name but icon is displaying as grey square box both in notification bar icon as well as push notification icon. How to solve this issue by displaying my icon in the both places? Thank you so much!

Comment: I already created the iOS stand alone app in Test Flight and still see the expo icon 